# Pushing query result from back end to front end with interval

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm playing around with sockets for the first time and have a created a very simple back end and front end to test with our system at work.

I want the back end to query our server every 10 seconds in this example and pass the results to the front end.

I currently have the interval set as 10 seconds however when I run it I only get the result after ten seconds - i want the result straight away and then to check every ten seconds for changes.

I've tried moving code around and seeing what works, but I usually get a message telling me the variable is undefined (because it is then obviously outside the function.

My code is below - I am aware its probably a it overkill having the set interval in both the result and catch, so if anyone can help tidy it up so it works correctly, I'd appreciate it. Still a bit of a noob I'm afraid!

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const oledb = require('oledb');

const smartconn =
  `--myodbcconnection--`;
const db = oledb.odbcConnection(smartconn);

let command = `SELECT item FROM mytable.table LIMIT 10`

db.query(command)
.then(result => {
    setInterval(function(){
        io.emit("query", result.result); 
    }, 10000);
},
err => {
    setInterval(function(){
        io.emit("query", err); 
    }, 10000);
});

io.set("origins", "*:*");

io.on("connection", async (socket) => {

console.log("Client Successfully Connected");


});
server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Backend Server is running on http://localhost:5000");
});
```

Expect results to show immediately. Previously the old method didn't use sockets and polled the using set interval from the front end, which I want to move away from.

Comment: I solved it for now by placing the io.emit parts in the io.on functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
//Resolves a Promise after ms milliseconds
const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
//Returns a db.query result with server status
const getServerStatus = async () => {
    return await db.query(`SELECT item FROM mytable.table LIMIT 10`);
}
//Runs indefinitely and emits events to frontend every 10 seconds
(async () => {
    while(true){
        try{
            const result = await getServerStatus();
            io.emit("query", result.result); 
        } catch (error){
            io.emit("query", error); //It would be better to change the event name to something else
        }
        await sleep(10000);
    }
})();
```

This way the first event will be sent immediately because unlike setInterval, my implementation waits **after** executing the code, not before. Also, you can be sure that queries will not overlap when they take more than 10s to execute. `setInterval` doesn't guarantee that the next execution will wait for the previous one to finish.

The downside is that events will be sent after (10,000ms + query_delay), so depending on your database size and performance, some of them might get delayed by a few or a few hundred milliseconds. To counter that, you can measure getServerStatus's execution time and subtract it from the wait time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got error with the above: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: I edited the code and wrapped the while loop in an async function. Refresh the page and check again.

Comment: Cheers, had another look - it still doesn't seem to load until after ten seconds still. I appreciate the help. hmm I'm going to keep playing with it till I crack it!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it, by moving the emit functions into the io.on function.

Cheers!